# Why html table cell's border color does not change?

Tags: html, css

How can I make left border of the cell red? Why this does not work? Thanks!!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.main-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.main-table td {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 1px 4px 1px 4px;
}
.left-border {
border-left: 1px solid red !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
```

Shouldn't left-border override the color specified on .main-table td?

```
<table class='main-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 366 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td > 2 </td>
    <td class='left-border'> 777 </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Set the border to `1px double red`. A 1px-wide "double" border looks identical to a "solid", but has higher precedence in collapsed border computation.

Comment: For reference, the rules for border conflict resolution in CSS2.1 are [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution).

Comment: If you are satisfied with an answer on StackOverflow, please Accept it by cicking the check mark under the vote score.

Comment: This is still valid. Use double style for the top layer border, and solid under it, otherwise, if both borders are having the same style than it wont work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
.main-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.left-border {
border-left: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

Comment: Does not do what the question asks.

Comment: 2px wide border works. However, what I need is a 1px red border in this case. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

In CSS the selector that is most specific takes precedence over the lesser specific ones. For example, in your case `.main-table td` takes precedence over `.left-border` since the former is more specific. To solve it, you can specify: `.main-table td.left-border` for the border override. This is more correct and better than using `!important` which eliminates all chances of overriding it further.

See this link for info on CSS selector precedence: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: The `!important` circumvents this issue, although I do argee that it's better to use specificity than rely on `!important`

Answer (score 1):

I would go with anglimass, but with one change to the css:

```
td.left-border {
border-left: 1px double red !important;
}
```

That is, the selector should have the additional "td"

(Edited the 2px border to 1px - that was a mistake!)

Comment: It's changing solid to double what helps. Setting border width to 2px helps change the colour as well even when solid. However, what I needed was 1px border. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. It almost seems like this depends on the order in which the cell borders are drawn by the browser.  I tried the above in IE8 and it looked fine, but didn't work in FF or Chrome.

Then I tried making the right border of the left cell red instead, using the exact same markup.  This time it didn't work in IE but did work in FF and Chrome.

If you make both the left border of the right cell red and the right border of the left cell red, it works in all of them.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.main-table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.main-table td
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 1px 4px 1px 4px;
}
.right-border
{
    border-right: 1px solid red !important;
}
.left-border
{
    border-left: 1px solid red !important;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table class='main-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
        <tr>
            <td> 1 </td>
            <td> 366 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='right-border'> 2 </td>
            <td class='left-border'> 777 </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution,

http://jsfiddle.net/yPSVg/

```css
.main-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.main-table td {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 1px 4px 1px 4px;
}
.left-border {
    border-left: 1px solid red !important;
}
.right-border {
    border-right: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<table class='main-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
  <tr>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td> 366 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="right-border"> 2 </td>
      <td class='left-border'> 777 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `collapse` value means borders are collapsed into a single border when possible.
You want to use `separate` for the `border-collapse` property.

Also, You have two closing `</head>` tags.

Comment: Does not do what the question asks.

Comment: @Kolink: Why don't we let the person who asked the question decide?

Comment: Because you should try to keep to what they ask unless there's no alternative? I know that when I use `border-collapse:collapse` I do it for a reason, and that reason is to override the default `separate` to produce the effect of my choice.

Comment: It's possible that he/she didn't do it for a reason (could be copy/pasting code, reading a tutorial, etc).

Comment: Guys, I think collapse is redundant in my code. However changing it to separate or any other value does not change a thing, or solve the problem.