# how to have table cell border override neighbour table cell borders

Tags: html, css

So in the example below, you will see that the black border only covers the bottom and right side, whereas I'd want it to override the left and top side as well. Is there anyway around this?

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

table td.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="border"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the border to 1px **double** black.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

table td.border {
  border: 1px double black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="border"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

[see here already answered by someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906313/why-html-table-cells-border-color-does-not-change)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is using a `pseudo` element like so:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

table td.border {
  position: relative;
}
table td.border:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  top: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: a good answer, though it would be better to copy my snippet next time and edit that so it's easier for me to validate.